# Kivy-Python working in multi processing opening one more white screen

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy, screen, kivy-language

```
    import file...
    from mobus import modbus
    .....

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class mainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        iconfonts.register('default_font', 'iconfonts\gar.ttf',
                           join(dirname(__file__), 'iconfonts\gar.fontd'))

        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1080')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')
        return Builder.load_file("my.kv")


def de():
    mainApp().run()

def modbusStart():
    modbus.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a = Process(target=de)
    b = Process(target=modbusStart)
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

[Screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMXLZ.png)
When ı runnnig this code opening one more window that is white. I dont know why is opening and how ı can fix it?
I think it's about Screen Manager and 2.process. I tried all combination to fix it but I cant

Comment: Cannot tell anything from that little bit of code. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying something like your code on `Ubuntu` and `Windows 10`, I found some strange behavior. First, the extra `Window` only seems to appear on `Windows` and only if you import `MDApp`. Even if you just import `MDApp`, and do not actually use it, the extra `Window` behavior happens.

I think you have found a bug that you should report to the `kivyMD` developers.

The only way I could find to stop the extra `Window` behavior was to not use (and not even import) `MDApp`.

Comment: Thank you when I try your solutions it's work. I am gonna report that

Answer (score 0):

Main.py

```
import modbus
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, freeze_support
import kvy

def kivy():
    kvy.de()

def modbusStart():
    modbus.connect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Process(target=kivy)
    b = Process(target=modbusStart)
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

Kivy

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,FadeTransition
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from iconfonts import iconfonts
from os.path import join, dirname


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior,Image):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class mainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        iconfonts.register('default_font', 'iconfonts\gar.ttf',
                           join(dirname(__file__), 'iconfonts\gar.fontd'))
        LabelBase.register(name="prototype", fn_regular="font/Prototype.ttf")

        Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1080')
        Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')
        return Builder.load_file("my.kv")

def de():
    mainApp().run()
```

Modbus

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

def connect():
    client = ModbusTcpClient("localhost")
    client.connect()
    if client.connect():
        print("Connection Successful")
    else:
        print("Conenction Failed")
```